# Highlight Table Row Based On Column Value Equal To Value In Another Table Column

Tags: excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I have two tables, `tblPO` in sheet `Purchase Order` and `tblRiskItems` in sheet `Risky Items`. `tblPO` is used for the purchase order that has columns `Item #`, `Description`, `Unit Price` and `Line Total`. `tblRiskItems` contains a list of our items that are either fast movers, slow movers or obsolete, having columns `Item #`, `Description` and `Status` (this column showing whether an item is fast or slow moving or obsolete). Below are pictures of my tables:

#### tblPO

[image: tblPO]

#### tblRiskItems

[image: tblRiskItems]

What I need is to higlight the entire row in `tblPO` where it’s `Item #` matches `tblRiskItems`’ `Item #` so that the user knows ordering that item is a risk and needs to be followed up. It would also be great to format the row based on the value in column `Status` of `tblRiskItems`, for e.g. green if item is fast moving, yellow if item is slow moving and red if item is obsolete.

My efforts with Conditional Formatting has ended in a disaster. If anyone can suggest how I will be able to achieve this it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simple way will be to use a helper column on the table `tblPO` to get the relevant status from `tblRiskItems`, and then formatting the rows of `tblPO` based on that column. Here is how you do it:

**1. Set the helper column in table `tblPO`**

Create a new column named `status`, and paste in the first data row the formula:

`=IF(ISTEXT(VLOOKUP(A2,tblRiskItems,MATCH("status",tblRiskItems[#Headers],0),FALSE)),VLOOKUP(A2,tblRiskItems,MATCH("status",tblRiskItems[#Headers],0),FALSE),"No")`

This formula copies the value in the `tblRiskItems` on the column named for the `status` to the cell where you pasted it, and if the item doesn't  exist it returns "No". After placing it in the first cell you can simply drag it down to the end.

[image: Getting the status]

**2. Formatting the table**

Choose the first row of data in table `tblPO`, then set a formatting rule as: `=$D2="slow"`, where `D` is the helper column you just made, *Notice the reference style - only the column is fixed*. Set the formatting as you like, and repeat this steps for every status value (i.e. "slow", "fast", etc..).

[image: Set the formatting rules]

After you finished to set **all** the conditional formatting rules for the first row, drag it down to the end, and change the setting to "Fill formatting only".

[image: Copy the formatting]

And you're done!

If for some reason you really don't want to use a helper column than you need to copy all the formula from step 1 above into the conditional formatting rule (I didn't try it, though).

Hope it solved your problem ;)

Comment: @LuiP3rd Please consider [marking this as the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem, so it will help others ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Item #` is in `C6` on both sheets, I suggest selecting the entire PO table and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=VLOOKUP($C6,'Risky Items'!$C$6:$E$17,3,0)="Very Slow Moving"  
=VLOOKUP($C6,'Risky Items'!$C$6:$E$17,3,0)="Obsolete"  
=VLOOKUP($C6,'Risky Items'!$C$6:$E$17,3,0)="Fast"
```

each with a different choice of formatting (and lookup text to suit) – in sequence yellow, red, green.